# Div Spacing between Images

Tags: html, css

Dear Members of this amazing Forum

I recently started using Html again and for the love of God i can't figure out where the problem is.

I created 3 Div's, each with 1 image, 1 group of images, and 1 image again. (same problem if all are in the same div, with a rather basic Css)

```
.HeaderNav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

And the Html to use it.

```
<div class="HeaderNav">
    <img src="../Images/shang3_03.jpg" alt="" width="940" height="120" class="HeaderNav" />
</div>
<div class="HeaderNav">
    <img src="../Images/shang3_05.jpg" alt="" width="240" height="55" />
    <img src="../Images/shang3_06.jpg" alt="" width="66" height="55" />
    <img src="../Images/shang3_07.jpg" alt="" width="84" height="55" />
    <img src="../Images/shang3_08.jpg" alt="" width="72" height="55" />
    <img src="../Images/shang3_09.jpg" alt="" width="74" height="55" />
    <img src="../Images/shang3_10.jpg" alt="" width="107" height="55" />
    <img src="../Images/shang3_11.jpg" alt="" width="62" height="55" />
    <img src="../Images/shang3_12.jpg" alt="" width="70" height="55" />
    <img src="../Images/shang3_13.jpg" alt="" width="165" height="55" />
</div>
<div class="HeaderNav">
    <img src="../Images/shang3_14.jpg" alt="" width="940" height="133" />
    <br/>
</div>
```

What results in the image below, sadly i don't get where the little space is from. Or why it's not on top too. Somehow i'm really confused where this issue is from and i'd realy appreciate the help.

[image]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/52LOf.png <-- this one schould be a bit more clear sorry about that

edit: if found a rather face-> wall way to fix it with margin-top. And just making a div class for everyline. What's probably not the best way to go.

Comment: I don't see any *little space* o.0 is it just me..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a few things here.

For one, with questions like this, it helps people answering a LOT if you post your code in a JSFiddle, like [this here](http://jsfiddle.net/98TwV/) (though the images don't show there because they're relative URLs).

Also, it seems if you float the images to the left you can get rid of the spacing:

```
.HeaderNav img {
    float: left;
}
```

Just to note, I have no idea why the spacing existed in the first place. Another tip: you should use 'Inspect Element' in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox to take a look at elements and see padding, margins, etc. Usually that makes it obvious where whitespace is coming from, though in this case I found nothing. Floating to the left was just an idea that seemed to work.

Comment: Okay, ill try to use css for the width and height. But woudn't that require a new class for every image?
2. ok sorry didn't even know this site :P 

ill thry the img float

Comment: .HeaderNav img {
    float: left;
}  
Fixed the issue, if i only knew why now. Since i hate behaviour that don't realy make a lot of sence by itself.

Comment: @darkminaz Yeah I agree it's annoying to not know. As for the CSS, if you create a rule that sets the height of all images to 55px (`.HeaderNav img { height: 55px; }`) it'll automatically set the width to keep the ratio of the image the same. If you wanted different widths you can just use inline CSS on the images - `style="width: Xpx;"` instead of `width="X"`

Comment: the problem is i got sizes from 12px till 500px. So id have to create one for every image.
But ill try it out later. Might be just a bad habbit of mine and ill like that way at one point.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your `<img>` are still being declared as inline-level elements. Use:

```
.HeaderNav img {
    display: block;
}
```

Also, you should check if a margin or padding have been assigned to the image element. If you do, reset them.

Comment: Display:block did add even more spacing and pushed every image on it's own line. 
but thanks anyway, might need it later for something.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure your padding and margin are 0 for the html and body...

so, try this:

```
    body, html {

         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
    }
```

HTML cannot be used on it's own; it has to have CSS working with it continuously.

Comment: Sadly this changed nothing as far as i can tell. But thanks for the fast help.

Answer (score 0):

A bit confusing question, I don't understand it all. But check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LvWj/1/). Is this what you mean?

Also remove the *HeaderNav* class from the first image.

```
<div class="HeaderNav">
<img src="../Images/shang3_03.jpg" alt="" width="940" height="120" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The img element default display type like inline-block, because of the font-size, so the img element maybe have 3px space.

To solve this problem, you can use the code below:

```
.HeaderNav img {
    display: block;
}
```

or

```
.HeaderNav img {
    float: left;
}
```

They all will change the img elements display type, I recommend the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on why images have a space by default, that kinda explains why it did behave like this.

Comment: That's ok, but I really recommend use display block instead of float left.